# How can I add a custom hash to my Ajax form submission via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am submitting a form like so:

```
formdata = $("#app_form").serialize()
formdata['apps'] = apps
hash = { type: "POST", url: "create_all", data: formdata }
$.ajax(hash)
```

The **formdata** posts, but the line:

```
formdata['apps'] = apps
```

is **completely ignored**. I can't understand how Coffeescript and Javascript can just ignore a line completely. Very interesting.

The *apps* hash has the following structure:

```
{ "a" => { "1", "2", "3" },
  "b" => { "4", "5", "6" },
  ...
  "n" => { "x", "y", "z" } }
```

If:

```
formdata['apps'] = apps
```

doesn't work after doing:

```
formdata = $("#app_form").serialize()
```

then how can I add the **apps** hash to the **formdata** hash prior to submission?

Comment: According to the [jQuery documentation for serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), the function returns a **string**, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns a query string not an object, so to add a argument to the query string use string concatenation

```
formdata += '&apps=' + encodeURIComponent(apps);
```

assuming apps is a string.

Answer (score 1):

The [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) routine is expecting an object (hash), so you do not really want to serialize to a string at all, just pull in all the form data.

Fortunately, there is a version of the command in jQuery prior to the form data version [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) - however, this produces an array of the form:

`[ {'name': ..., 'value': ... }, ...]`- not what you would want.

So you can either replicate how it retrieves all the form elements, which is a fairly complex filter.  Or you can just rearrange the output from that in to what you need.

Your `apps` variable would not comfortably be passed via AJAX, it would need converting to JSON first I think (or some other form of serialization), using `JSON.stringify()`.  This is built-in to most browsers now, but it's advisable to load [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) with jQuery as a backup (it only engages if the native routine is not available).  You can restore `apps` from JSON in whatever backend language you use using native JSON decode routines, which almost all languages have now.

```
var formdata = { 'apps': JSON.stringify(apps) };
$.each($("#app_form").serializeArray(), function(cIndex, cEntry) {
    formdata[cEntry.name] = cEntry.value;
});

$.ajax({ type: "post",
         url: "create_all",
         data: formdata }};
```

Answer (score -1):

from what you have stated that doesnt look like valid json and jquery data parameter expects valid json..

why dont you use something like `JSON.parse($("#app_form").serialize())`